# Console Warning in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm with my react native app and when I run it I get the following error:

```
Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`, expected one of type[number].
```

In the react.development.js file:

```
Function.prototype.apply.call(console[level], console, argsWithFormat);
^
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the source code where the Image component is used.

Double-check the syntax towards the docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/image